# Re-add existing function to event

Tags: javascript, events

What happens if I re-add an existing function to the same event? Is it bad practice to do that, or should I check if the function is already added?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var my = document.getElementById('my');

my.addEventListener('click', someFunc);


var index = 0;

function someFunc() {
  my.innerHTML = index++;
  my.addEventListener('click', someFunc);
}
```

```css
#my {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="my"></div>
```

Comment: `What happens if I re-add an existing function to the same event?` it will be executed twice.

Comment: Why do you need to add it a second time? Adding it once would be enough

Comment: @vlaz But if you run the code posted in the question the number goes up by 1, not 2, when you click on the div.

Comment: @Pipe In my project, there's code that checks if the event should get removed or added. (The logic behind the if statement is irrelevant.) If the if statement says to add the event,  I want to know if it's necessary to make an additional if statement checking if it already has an event. (Hope this is clear. Let me know.)

Comment: This code is very strange. Every time you click the element, it will add another listener. Assuming you start off with 1 listener, it grows to 2 then 4 then 8 etc. This can't be what you need.

Comment: @Halcyon But if you run the code posted in the question the number goes up by 1, not 2 then 4 then 8, when you click on the div

Comment: Ah, then that answers your question. Apparently it keeps a unique list of functions. I suppose that makes sense because of how `removeListener` works.

Comment: @Halcyon So I don't need to make a check if the function was already added, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> Multiple identical event listeners
>
> If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same
>   EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are
>   discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and
>   since the duplicates are discarded, they do not need to be removed
>   manually with the removeEventListener method.

So, if you add the same function twice, it will be executed once. but if you add two diferrent functions, both will be called.

Comment: So I don't need to make a check if the function was already added, correct?